# Gradually fading a surface using fill

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, alpha, fill

I'm trying to fade a surface over a period of time for a game that I'm currently making. It's the first time I've used an alpha value with the `surface.fill()` method, and after reading the documentation I assumed it would be fairly straight forward. However, I keep getting the error: `pygame.error`

This in itself is rather vague, I don't actually know what's wrong. So would someone be able to suggest an alternative to the method I'm using, or simply explain how to use `surface.fill()` properly?

Here's an example of some code I wrote to demonstrate what I wish to achieve.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))

fade = 0
while True:
    SCREEN.fill((0, 0, 0))
    SCREEN.fill((250, 248, 239, fade), None, pygame.SRCALPHA)

    fade += 1

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SRCALPHA` is not a valid for `special_flags`. Take a look at the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill).

`SRCALPHA` is only used when creating surfaces (since it is usually a read-only flag).

---

Your code should look like this:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))

surf = pygame.Surface((300, 300), pygame.SRCALPHA)

fade = 0
while True:
    if pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT): break
    pygame.event.pump()

    SCREEN.fill((0, 0, 0))
    surf.fill((250, 248, 239, fade))
    SCREEN.blit(surf, (0, 0))

    if fade < 255:
        fade += 1
    pygame.display.update()
```

Don't try to fill the screen surface with an RGBA color. Use a `Surface` with the `SRCALPHA` flag instead.

Note that `fade` should never be bigger than 255. Otherwise, you'll get an invalid color argument exception.